# search and find the index of a string in multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array, and i want to find a string in that array that the user inputs. And i want to store it's index(both of them, like of the string is at `arr[a][b]`, i need both the values of `a` and `b`.

For example, i have an array as following and want to find the word "scar", how can i get it?

```
var arr=[["hey","oh"],["scar","tissue"],["other","side"]];
```

I have tried the following block :

```
var a;
var b;

for (var z = 0; z < arr.length; z++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (arr[z][i] === "scar") {
      b = z;  
      a = i;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried searching and researching the question but couldn't find one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2cm7u216/

Comment: Your code appears to work. It sets `b` to `1` and `a` to `0` as expected. What did you get when you ran it? I don't like the `i < 2` part, though - that should use the `.length` of the inner array. Or you could use `.indexOf()` as in Satpal's fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can search your string in many way

using a nested `for-for`

```
for (a = 0; a < arr.length; a++){
  for (b=0; b < arr[a].length; b++){
    if (arr[a][b] == mySearch){
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

using a nested `forEach`

```
var found = false;
arr.forEach(function(a) {
  a.forEach(function(b) {
    if (b == wordToFind) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
});

return found;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop each subarray and then with the function `indexOf()` check if the required index is found:

```js
var arr = [["hey","oh"], ["scar","tissue"], ["other","side"]];

function get_index_of_string(my_array, mystring) {
  var a = 0;
  var results = [];
  var b, subarray;
  
  for (var arrayIndex in my_array) {
    subarray = my_array[arrayIndex];
    var search = subarray.indexOf(mystring)
    
    if (search != -1){
        a++;
        b = search;
    }
  }

  results[0] = a;
  results[1] = b;
  
  return results;
}

var results = get_index_of_string(arr,"scar");

if (results[0] != -1 && results[1] != -1) {
  alert("String is found in  the " + results[0] + " subarray in the " + results[1] + " index");
} else{
  alert("String is not found");
}
```